# is there a way to have fixed headers on android

Tags: android, mobile, web, iscroll

If I use position:fixed for a header, it stays fixed however on android there is a bug where if you have any fixed position divs present when you focus an input element, the page does crazy scrolling jumping about all over the place when you type.

so, I thought the solution was something like iscroll, so i can keep everything to position: absolute instead.

However, even the new iscroll5 doesnt allow android to use any SELECT inputs within an iscroll, it just doesnt focus them. On top of this, any input elements get the input overlay appearing but not over the top of the input, another bug of android..

Is there any way to get fixed header/ other elements that works on android? is there a different script to iscroll which can use form elements without hassle?

Answer (score 1):

in IScroll 5 you can add the parameter preventDefaultException for enabling click of any input and for this example any element having the class .placeholder, .label. Example :

```
this.scroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', 
{
    preventDefaultException: { 
        tagName: /^(INPUT|TEXTAREA|BUTTON|SELECT|LABEL|SPAN)$/,
        className:/^(placeholder|label)$/ 
    }
});
```